# What should the result of extraction be after deploying a Clojure WAR web application to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, clojure, war, compojure

**Addendum**: I have managed to get my Clojure application working on a local installation of Tomcat 8.0.28, so I really don't know what's going on anymore. It involved binding my database connection's IP to a hostname (so that on deployment it will use some kind of `sym-link`) and a bunch of other fixes such as context-based routing so I really don't have a clue why I can't get this thing running on a Tomcat installation on a different machine despite having direct access to it...

---

I am building a relatively basic CRUD application in Clojure using Ring and Compojure (combined with YESQL and Friend) which I have named `emt-admin` and so far my code has been built in such a way that testing it using `lein ring server-headless` has resulted in basically no problems. However after using `lein ring uberwar` as written [in this website](https://fitacular.com/blog/clojure/2014/07/14/deploy-clojure-tomcat-nginx/) I have discovered that after navigating to the path indicated in `/webapps/emt-admin/` which would be something like `http://<address>:8080/emt-admin` (as my Tomcat installation is running on a server separate from my development machine) I get a blank page and automatically get directed to `http://<address>:8080/login`.

I would like to confirm that when the WAR file is deployed on the Tomcat installation, there should only be `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` folders, right? All of my static resources are in subdirectories of the `WEB-INF` folder and I have no clue if my static files are being served, as when I navigate to my deployed web-app I get a blank page.

The person [who made this](https://github.com/simax/webdev) and asked a question on StackOverflow about it made some modifications to his code to make the application more "context friendly" but I don't completely understand his `diff` changes.

EDIT: I've been trying to work on this on my own and I have been investigating my Tomcat installation logs:

```
29-Oct-2015 11:47:15.145 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/emt-admin.war
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.133 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.145 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/emt-admin] startup failed due to previous errors
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.147 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [emt-admin] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.148 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [emt-admin] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.150 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/emt-admin.war has finished in 136,005 ms
```

What's the meaning behind "Error listenerStart"?

My core handler looks like this:

```
(ns reporter.core
  (:require [reporter.views.start :as start]
            [reporter.routes.home :as home]
            [compojure.core :as compojure :refer (GET defroutes)]
            [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]
            ring.adapter.jetty)
(:gen-class))

(def site-appli (compojure/routes
                       home/secured-appli))

(defn run
  []
  (defonce privserver
    (ring.adapter.jetty/run-jetty #'site-appli {:port 3000 :join? false})))
```

After a while it just dies:

```
29-Oct-2015 11:53:35.767 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Further inspection of logs gave me what I think is the culprit:

```
29-Oct-2015 11:49:31.133 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class reporter.listener
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I'm going to see what happens if I fix my DB connection spec

Answer (score 0):

**Well, it seems like I've managed to get the damn thing finally working, so I'll answer my own question**. To lay out what I've done, I've had to take the liberty of redacting certain sensitive information from my code, but my general point should still be pretty clear. **I should also probably mention that the guys with actual control over the server I was trying to access increased the `PermGen` size to 10g**

**Database Specification**

I had to modify my database connection spec so it looks like this:

```
(ns reporter.db.core
  (:require
   [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
   [yesql.core :refer [defqueries]]
   [taoensso.timbre :as timbre]))

(def connprod
  {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   :subprotocol "mysql"
   :subname "//db-emt.my_domain.com/match_ticker" ; the name of my database
   :user "my_user_name"
   :password "my_password"})

(defqueries "sql/queries.sql" {:connection connprod})
```

On my development machine I had to put `db-emt.my_domain.com` in my `hosts` file and link it to the public IP it was assigned to. Originally `:subname` pointed directly to the IP.

**DB Transactions**

After modifying my connection spec I decided to wrap my YESQL transactions by using `clojure.java.jdbc`'s `with-db-transaction` just to be safe. I'm not actually sure if this was a necessary step, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

**Context Routing**

I forgot to include the Hiccup `wrap-base-url` middleware. Whoops

Furthermore, I decided to replace my naked Hiccup references to use stuff such as `(include-js)` and `(include-html)`. I've also used `(form-to)` in some cases just to be sure.

So now in my Tomcat server logs I'm getting successful `200` responses like this:

```
61.93.195.138 - - [29/Oct/2015:16:12:23 +0800] "GET /emt-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2244
61.93.195.138 - - [29/Oct/2015:16:12:23 +0800] "GET /emt-admin/css/foundation-datepicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2616
61.93.195.138 - - [29/Oct/2015:16:12:23 +0800] "GET /emt-admin/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7708
```

**Moving Forward**

Moving forward I've decided just to work directly with Tomcat as a container instead of using `lein ring server` in order to check that any further work I do on this project won't break crap.